# In MATLAB, how to compare the elements of 2 vectors in the most efficient way?

Tags: matlab

I have a vector **r**, which stores the previously taken actions. Let,

```
r=[8,8,8,2,2,6,6, ... , 4,4,4];     % (8:up, 2:down, 4:left,  6:right)
```

and I have a second vector **actions** that indicates the currently available actions. Let,

```
actions=[2,6,8];
[~,n]=size(actions);
```

and let **n** indicate the number of available actions. I want to compare the **last n** elements of vector **r** with the elements of vector **actions** and eliminate the current action that is in the opposite direction i.e. to avoid repetitions.

For example, since in this case vector **r** indicates that the last action was towards **left**, in vector **actions** 6 should be eliminated and the result would be

```
actions=[2,8];
```

What is an efficient (i.e. ideally by avoiding loops) way of achieving this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would define an array with the oposite actions, that in this case would be

```
oposite=[0 8 0 6 0 4 0 2]% (8:up, 2:down, 4:left,  6:right)
```

Then, to remove from actions the ones that have been used in tha last n you just use bsxfun to do singleton expansion of the equal function, so that actions would be:

```
actions(any(bsxfun(@eq,oposite(actions)',r(end-n+1:end)),2))=[];
```

That's it, just one line once 'oposite' is defined.

Comment: Great answer, but it should be end-n+1 instead of end-n.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by defining a matrix that held the opposite action pairs.  Then takes the last n- unqiue values of `r` and removes its `pair` from the actions array.

```
pairs = [2 8;...
         8 2; ...
         4 6; ...
         6 4];

r=[8,8,8,2,2,6,6,4,4,4];  
actions=[2,6,8];
[~,n]=size(actions);

%The unique last n-values of r
lastN_r   = unique(r(end-n+1:end));
%Where these are in the pairs matrix
matchI    = ismember(pairs(:,1),lastN_r);
%Remove them.
parsedAct = actions(~ismember(actions,pairs(matchI,2)))

parsedAct =    
     2     8
```